# Linux given a timestamp, how to get the timestamp X days ago?

Tags: linux, date

How to use the `date` command, and given a timestamp, to get the timestamp `X` days ago. For example UTC time stamp is `1525192000`, I want to get the UTC timestamp `30` days before that.

Answer (score 6):

For a start, your time stamp is in seconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC is my assumption, if it is not, convert it to that.

So, you have to subtract the seconds for the days you want.

```
stamp=1525192000
day=$((60*60*24))
echo $(($stamp - 30*$day))
```

You then get a Unix epoch time back, if that needs conversion to date and time of day, you may have to take DST into account, and that's where you may need to use the `date` utility.

Note, that you can also use `date`. This allows you to work with other date elements easily, no calculation needed:

With GNU `date`:

```
date --date="$(date --iso-8601=s -d @1525192000) -30 days" +%s
```

Example:

```
 $ date --date="$(date --iso-8601=s -d @1525192000)"
 Tue, May  1, 2018  7:06:01 PM
 $ date --date="$(date --iso-8601=s -d @1525192000) -30 days"
 Wed, Apr 1, 2018  7:06:01 PM
 $ date --date="$(date --iso-8601=s -d @1525192000) -30 days" +%s
 1523466380
 $ date --date="$(date --iso-8601=s -d @1525192000) -30 days -1 week -3 months" +%s
 1514309200
```

In FreeBSD and macOS (the `-j` means do not attempt to set system date, nice and safe)

```
date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "$(date -r 1234567890)"  -v-30d "+%s"
```

EDIT: Thanks, Kusalananda, OpenBSD and NetBSD do not support `-v`.

Comment: @StephenKitt, 24 hours of 3600 seconds each is one of the most common definition of day. It's true that when considering calendar dates, there are other definition of _day_ some of which can have 23 or 25 hours because of  DST change, one might want to consider leap seconds in some contexts, but here the OP is not asking for dates and is not mentioning any calendar representation, just what looks like a Unix epoch timestamp. Taking 30x24x60x60 off that number is the only reasonable answer to give here without more context.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it because the `date` command was not used? Note that one can always use `date` as a replacement for `echo` with `date "+$((stamp - 30 * day))"`

Comment: I did not downvote, I thought it was an interesting question. I get downvotes, too ... thing is, time is complex. leap years, DST (that changes every now and then, US has changed its DST date some years back), timezones that change (North Korea's has just changed) ... all this makes it very hard, UTC helps somewhat. Then you have calendar changes, if you want to go back centuries, like prior to December 1582.

Comment: Note that I was referring to the downvote on your answer (which currently has one down vote and one up vote (mine, before the edit)), not the  question. Note that the OP is not making any reference to any date (other than the `date` utility) or any calendar. For all we know, they may not be using the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: The downvote comes from my silly mistake, I leave it there because others might think that it is a good idea to calculate days, it sounds logical, of course, but is `very` dangerous. We all make mistakes and learn from them (I wrote that up after my first coffee ... was not quite awake), if people can learn from my mistakes, all the better. BTW, I learned how to use GNU `date` as well ;-).

Comment: Note that Unix epoch time is not related to timezones and not much to UTC. They identify instant in times based on an offset to another precise instant in time (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC even if UTC didn't exist at the time). That's as a number of Unix seconds that are not UTC seconds. They (contrary to UTC seconds) have a variable duration as there are always 86400 of them in an Earth solar day. So substracting 30x24x60x60 is again **the** correct  thing to do unless you want to define "day" as 86400 UTC seconds (which doesn't match the earth solar day)

Comment: (to further clarify, my "Why the downvote?" was not a question to you, but to whomever downvoted the answer).

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane, I [stand corrected](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16). thecarpy, feel free to revert your edit, or perhaps remove the Java version — having the `date`-based variants seems useful to me on top of the initial 86400-based calculation.

Comment: Your "BSD" does not include OpenBSD.

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits which fix some of the issues in your answer.